# Multiple payment targets

Tags: commerce

I have a scenario where payments should be made to different targets based on some conditions. I was considering multi-store approach but I felt it might be a overkill considering that we only need payment targets and not complete store management.

Is there any simpler way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Which payment gateway are you planning to use? If it is Paypal, then there is this system called [Adaptive payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) which helps you split payments.